# Is bottom sheet for a responsive web page a good idea?

Tags: user-centered-design

I understand bottom sheets have great use cases and are used in several apps but I’ve only seen them in native mobile applications. So I was wondering if this is not the same when it comes to responsive webpages that are viewed on mobile

Comment: they are relatively common. of course, as long as you have a few items

Comment: @Devin I don't think they are common for responsive web pages. Care to share some examples?

Comment: I don't have examples, sorry. But notice i said *"relatively common"*, not *"common"*. I used to see one popping here and there 3-4 years ago when it was some kind of mini-fad,more or less by the time of *neumorphism*. I even built one myself which is not online anymore. Then again, it's only useful if you have few items and it won't behave exactly like an app, because it's just a fixed footer. EDIT: I did a quick search and even one of the most popular WordPress builders allows to do it, see https://medium.com/@codewatchers/how-to-create-a-sticky-footer-for-mobile-in-divi-f91542d4fa2f

Answer (score 0):

They also can be found in mobile web applications (eg things like m.youtube.com). Main upside of them would be that you can use an almost-native app, main downside would be that most "normal" websites tend to have just more stuff than you *can* put down there, with nothing that massively benefits from this style of navigation.

So the answer to "is it a good idea" is a clear "depends on your web page".

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to do what you think is right and don't think about the norms. You'll get proper feedback once you do what you think is correct and put it to test by users.